# Find Microsoft Account Token in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, desktop-bridge

I've got a WPF application I've published it in the store using Desktop Bridge. 
I've setup

- some add-ons,
- a customer group with people on it
- a targeted offer for an add-on and the customer group (defined above)

When a user of this group install the application, (s)he is not granted to the add-on.

**How can I fix this?**

I've found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/monetize/manage-targeted-offers-using-windows-store-services) but it should be executed in the UWP application and mine is WPF released through Desktop Bridge.

### Further information:

When I try to retrieve a MSA token with this code:

```
    private async Task<string> GetMicrosoftAccountTokenAsync()
    {
        var msaProvider = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync(
            "https://login.microsoft.com", "consumers");

        var request = new WebTokenRequest(msaProvider, "devcenter_implicit.basic,wl.basic");            
        var result = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request);

        return (result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
            ? result.ResponseData[0].Token
            : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I have this error when trying to execute this line: `await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request);`

> **System.Exception:** 'Resource Contexts may not be created on threads that do not have a CoreWindow. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073B27)'

How can I specify a CoreWindow on my WPF `UserControl`

Comment: Same for me. Any News?

Answer (score 0):

As the [Use targeted offers to maximize engagement and conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/use-targeted-offers-to-maximize-engagement-and-conversions) topic tips,

> Targeted offers can only be used with UWP apps that include add-ons.

But your app is a packaged WPF app, according to the [UWP APIs available to a packaged desktop app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) document,

> Most UWP APIs work well on packaged desktop apps. However, some feature areas are not yet fully tested or currently functioning as intended.

So you can have a try with the Targeted offers in your desktop bridged wpf app following the [Use targeted offers to maximize engagement and conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/use-targeted-offers-to-maximize-engagement-and-conversions) document to create the offer in your dashboard and implement the in-app offer experience then submit your app to the Store.